# Jquery can´t select image inside link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a image inside a link.

JQUERY:

```
$('#selskaber img').hover(function () {
    $(this).next().css({'border' : '1px solid #0167B0 !important'});
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).next().css({'border' : '1px solid #CCCCCC !important'});
  }
);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="selskaber">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
    <img style="border:none;" src="/images.pmg" alt="Telenor">
    </a>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I have removed the next(). Still no border is added.

My CSS:

```
#wrap #selskaber a {border:none;margin-left:10px;display:inline-block !important;
    height: 41px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 150px;}
```

Comment: Maybe removing the two `.next()` parts helps.

Comment: Get rid of `!important`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That image doesn't have any sibling, so next won't give you anything.

If you're trying to select the img, just remove the `next()`

```
    $('#selskaber img').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #0167B0 !important'});
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #CCCCCC !important'});
      }
    );
```

`next`:

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Comment: Did remove the !important. Did have this solution because a:hover didn't work or img:hover with CSS.

Answer (score 9):

Um... why are you using Javascript here?

```
#selskaber a img{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#selkskaber a:hover img{
    border: 1px solid #0167B0;
}
```

will do exactly the same thing, and be compatable down to IE6 with no JS required.

Comment: While this is a completely valid, he was asking for a jQuery way of doing it.  But I too agree: CSS for style.

Comment: I have tried it. They border is added if I use !important. But it is not changed on hover. I have updated my question with some CSS.

Comment: Aha I have a style tag on the image that is: border:none; just removed it.

Comment: Isn't it a known issue that hover doesn't quite work right cross-browser in jQuery?  I'd go with the CSS myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `'#selskaber img'` already gives you the image. So inside the hover callbacks if you need the image `$(this)` will suffice. No need to call `next`:

```
$('#selskaber img').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #0167B0 !important'});
}, 
function () {
    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #CCCCCC !important'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `next()`, you already selected the `img` tag:

```
$('#selskaber img').hover(function () {
  $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #0167B0 !important'});
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #CCCCCC !important'});
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` inside your functions is the `<img>`. `$(this).next()` is nothing, so just remove the call to `next()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no node after the `img` element.  The `$(this)` context is relative to the `img` element that it is hovering over.  Try removing `next()`.

```
$('#selskaber img').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #0167B0 !important'});
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #CCCCCC !important'});
    }
);
```